# GitHub Markdown and colors

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have a table with the following code. In the Markdown viewer and on GitHub pages, the color is shown correct. But not on GitHub.

```
|-   |-  |-   |-   |-   |
| <span style="font-family: Source Code Pro; padding: 20px; background-color: #000000; color: #fff;">#000000</span> |
```

The result on GitHub:

[image]

The result on GitHub Pages

[image]

A table has the disadvantage that it does not move downwards at smaller screen sizes, but only to the right. How can I create a kind of grid layout?

Answer (score 5):

Within GitHub, Markdown content is somewhat restricted. [After Markdown is converted to HTML](https://github.com/github/markup/tree/master#github-markup)

> The HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as `script` tags, **inline-styles**, and `class` or `id` attributes. See the [sanitization filter](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb) for the full whitelist.

(Bold added.)

The `span` tag is not included in the whitelist. Even if it was, the `style` attribute is also missing from the whitelist. The only way I know to achieve a visual similar to what's on GitHub Pages is to use an image, as you have done here.

Answer (score 3):

[The GitHub Flavored Markdown (GFM) Table Extension](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-) does not support coloring. Anything you do will be a hack that is not guaranteed to work going forward. It may be possible to accomplish this with HTML but I don't advocate mixing HTML with your Markdown. Support is sketchy and varied.