# GitHub flavored markdown: change background color of code block

Tags: html, css, markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I am making a website using GitHub Pages and would like to display output code with a white background rather than the default gray background for code elements (but keep the monospaced font).

In my *index.md* file, I've tried adding an inline HTML block to deal with this, since GitHub-flavored Markdown doesn't allow you to change the background for code elements.  I used the following code:

```
<pre><span style="display:block; background-color:white"><code>## Constructed an OTU  table and other variables with the following settings:
## thresh_prevalence: 80
## thresh_abundance: 0.5
## thresh_NA: 5
## subj: subject_1
</code></span></pre>
```

But the output does not have a white background. It instead has the default background color:

[image]

It seems that styles are not whitelisted in the GitHub-flavored version of Markdown. Is there a way to change the background color of a code block without style tags, or without HTML entirely?

Comment: I edited to clarify my question. Also, that post was closed as "unclear what you're asking" without a solution.

Comment: There are [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23904274/354577) of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11509830/354577) duplicate [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46211657/354577) with the same answer. Just because the person who asked that question didn't accept an answer doesn't mean the answer wasn't provided.